# Selenium select value from dropdown redirect page to another page

Tags: python, selenium, testcase

My appium test case using python+selenium re-direct page to home page when I am selecting an option from dropdown.

```
    def test_a(self):
       drop = self.driver.find_element_by_id("dropdown")
       self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@id='psic_code']/option[5]").click()
```

Can anyone give me a solution? Thank you.

Comment: so when you click on the browser it redirects but selenium clicks on it and it doesnt redirect?

Comment: no, opposite of it. when I click on browser, it isn't redirect, but selenium redirect to home page. it shouldn't be.

Comment: Try using the Select class instead maybe? ` drop = Select(self.driver.find_element_by_id("dropdown")` `drop.select_by_index(4)`

Comment: I tried it, It's saying 

`drop.select_by_index(4)
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: Ah sorry, I missed the "" `drop.select_by_index("4")` but you know you could have checked the docs to see why it was invalid. You know, experiment to find out the answer. Admittely I'm guessing "4" is actually the value you want based on the '[5]' in your xpath. You'd need to change that to what is relevant so you may want to use `drop.select_by_value("value")` or 'drop.select_by_visible_text("text")' instead.